# ERROR: UnknownPlatform: 'OSX'. Please file a ContactUs with DeveloperTools

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I am facing a weird issue wherein I am trying to build a project in Android Studio on a new mac and getting an error as

```
ERROR: UnknownPlatform: 'OSX'. Please file a ContactUs with DeveloperTools
```

whereas the same project is getting built completely fine on my older mac. 
My new mac has both Android Studio 3.4 as well as Android Studio 2.2 installed(same exist even in older macbook too). 
Till now I have tried uninstalling the android studio and going ahead with custom installation as well as standard installation too. I have even tried with uninstalling and reinstalling the SDK tools but till now there has been no progress. 
If anyone has come across such an issue and was able to resolve, please help me in the same.